# Edit SharePoint Page: All options are frozen

Tags: 2013, edit

I am at my homepage and click edit but all the options are frozen therefore I can not change font, move text boxes around etc. Any ideas?

[image]

I have been made a team member and owner of the page. The creator also see it like this.

Comment: Not much to go on there. Can you help us help you by identifying what browsers and browser versions you have tried and giving us much more in your screenshots?

Comment: There is owner of the site. and member of the site. Check your permissions on the site again. Also go check the back end code of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check which the browser you are using, open the IE browser with run with administrator and check.

If it does not work please check that the page you are workingon  is not checked out by some one else.

Here is the [link for your reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7af6521a-43ec-44c3-af47-65b7e7b0caf4/menu-options-disabledgreyed-out?forum=sharepointgeneral)